# Prolog: Why can't I use read(-Term) in a new thread?

Tags: multithreading, prolog

This is my code:

```
t1 :- read(X), write(X), nl, thread_exit(_).
t2 :- write(t2), nl.

start :- thread_create(t1, Id1, []),
         threads,
         thread_join(Id1, exited(_)),
         t2, threads.
```

There is an error in "read(X)".

Comment: What's the error message? And what prolog interpreter are you using?

Comment: I'm using swipl-win. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're using swipl-win, since the error shows up to me as well.

There is a bug in ConsoleEdit.cpp, where was not presumed that IO from different threads could run in the same console.

I've corrected it, and will push the fix... Not sure about availability though

Comment: Thanks! Based on your comment, I've found the "attach_console".